# Download multiple csv files in one zip folder in ASP .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, zip

I want to add two CSV file in one ZIP file. and download in ASP Net at Clint side.
I am using Data set to merge both data table record in one data set and need to download at button click. I am not sure this is good approach or not but, I am getting error on "Archive". I have added

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
```

But still [image: Here I have added screen shots:]
Is there any another way to do same. Please guide me

Code:

```
 protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = getDataCSV();
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            string csv = string.Empty;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    csv += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
                }
                csv += "\r\n";
            }
            DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[1];
            string csv1 = string.Empty;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt1.Columns)
                {
                    csv1 += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
                }
                csv1 += "\r\n";
            }
            using (FileStream zipFile = File.Open("compressed_files.zip", FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (FileStream source1 = File.Open(csv, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (FileStream source2 = File.Open(csv1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        using (var archive = new Archive())
                        {

                            // Add files to the archive

                            archive.CreateEntry(csv, source1);

                            archive.CreateEntry(csv1, source2);


                            archive.Save(zipFile, new ArchiveSaveOptions() { Encoding = Encoding.ASCII, ArchiveComment = "two files are compressed in this archive" });

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [`ArchiveSaveOptions`](https://apireference.aspose.com/zip/net/aspose.zip.saving/archivesaveoptions) seems to be part of a third-party library (Apose.Zip). Have you included a reference to that in your project?

Comment: @John No can you explain how to add ? is available in NuGet Package ? or need to externally download and then I need to add

Comment: I don't know. I've never used it. I suggest checking NuGet or consulting the Apose site. Alternatively, use the built-in zip functionality in the .NET framework.

Comment: @John can you give me sample code for adding both file in one zip file using built-in zip functionality in the .NET framework

Comment: Honestly, I've never had need to use either Apose's zip library nor the built in .NET framework zip functionality. I'd only be doing the same as you (consulting documentation samples, looking at examples online, trying it myself) if I were to create example code to you.

Comment: @John ok! hope any one reply but still not

Answer (score 0):

Can you add below screenshot nuget package in your project.

[image]

It's working properly with my code.